# Japanese encoding (ISO2022JP variants) for email communication

Tags: email, encoding

I would like have some information about Japanese e-mail encoding commonly used in Japan.

I know that *ISO-2022-JP* and *ISO-2022-JP-2* are used to encode emails in Japan. However, I do not have idea about how widely or rarely other ISO-2022-JP variant charsets ( For eg. **ISO-2022-JP-1**, **ISO-2022-JP-3** etc) are used in Japan for email encoding.
I have tried finding information on the internet, but have not been able to find out much about use of ISO-2022-JP-3, ISO-2022-JP-1 in email communications.

What is most common and important character encoding from ISO-2022-JP variants that is most widely used in Japan today for email communciations (including email communication on mobile)? 
It would be helpful, if someone with knowledge of Japanese encodings can provide information in this regard.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_2022

Answer (score 0):

Those variants are rarely used. Most people are using characters within ISO-2022-JP.

Some may want to use a rare character only available in ISO-2022-JP-1 (which, for example, can be rendered on Windows 7 but not on Windows Vista with default font), but not many MUA handle it correctly. ISO-2022-JP-2 is rarer, because it is for extended ISO-2022-JP with abilities to code Chinese/Korean/etc., and nowadays when Japanese need to write mail in non-Japanese/non-English language, more people are aware of switching encoding to UTF-8 (anyway regular Japanese do not have much chances to do that by e-mail). Forget about ISO-2022-JP-3.

Comment: Thanks akky, that was helpful. Do web-mails like Gmail JP, yahoo JP, provide options to switch to ISO-2022-JP-1, JP-2, JP-3 encoding ?

Comment: Gmail let you choose ISO-2022-JP (default) or UTF-8. Both headers and content are encoded in ISO-2022-JP.

Comment: If you make receiver side logic, it may need to support, or at least fallback-able with those rarely-used variations like -JP-2, -3. If you r logic is sender side, I think ISO-2022-JP is enough, unless your customers need to send some rare characters. But anyway, recipients's clients may not be able to display them correctly.